# Why can't I connect to CyberGhost VPN on Arch Linux? /Fix DNS Leaks Arch Linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ipv6

I have problems connecting to my VPN provider.

I can't use the script CyberGhost offers since it won't run on Arch Linux and only exits with `cyberghostvpn: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object`
upon launching

I'm using Gnome NetworkManager applet to connect to CyberGhost using .ovpn files they provide on their website.

It looks like it is able to establish a network connection for a short term, but then immediately aborts and notes something about the server configuration being wrong.
I was previously able to connect that way until I reinstalled my system.

NetworkManager log:

```
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195463.6919] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797" name="CG_Estland" pid=9655 uid=1000 result="success"
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195463.6944] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 26820
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195463.7017] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195463.7572] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195463.7573] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: WARNING: file '/home/leon/CyberGhost/client.key' is group or others accessible
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: OpenVPN 2.5.1 [git:makepkg/f186691b32e68362+] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 24 2021
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021, LZO 2.10
Mär 08 09:24:23 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]95.153.32.89:443
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: UDP link local: (not bound)
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]95.153.32.89:443
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1569', remote='link-mtu 1549'
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: WARNING: 'auth' is used inconsistently, local='auth SHA256', remote='auth [null-digest]'
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: WARNING: 'keysize' is used inconsistently, local='keysize 256', remote='keysize 128'
Mär 08 09:24:24 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: [tallinn-rack404.nodes.gen4.ninja] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]95.153.32.89:443
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: /usr/lib/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --debug 0 26820 --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_3 --tun -- tun0 1500 1552 10.203.6.105 255.255.255.0 init
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8616] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8670] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8682] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",5:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8690] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",5:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP6 Config Get) reply received
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <warn>  [1615195465.8690] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",5:(tun0)]: invalid IP6 config received!
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <warn>  [1615195465.8691] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",5:(tun0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: GID set to nm-openvpn
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: UID set to nm-openvpn
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: net_addr_v4_del: 10.203.6.105 dev tun0
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-1): Operation not permitted
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: Linux can't del IP from iface tun0
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8709] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8710] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Mär 08 09:24:25 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195465.8714] vpn-connection[0x56199a770330,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Mär 08 09:24:26 pwrpc nm-openvpn[26827]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195683.1628] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797" name="CG_Estland" pid=9655 uid=1000 result="success"
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195683.1651] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 27397
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195683.1724] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195683.2141] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195683.2142] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: WARNING: file '/home/leon/CyberGhost/client.key' is group or others accessible
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: OpenVPN 2.5.1 [git:makepkg/f186691b32e68362+] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 24 2021
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021, LZO 2.10
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]95.153.32.89:443
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: UDP link local: (not bound)
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]95.153.32.89:443
Mär 08 09:28:03 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Mär 08 09:28:04 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1569', remote='link-mtu 1549'
Mär 08 09:28:04 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: WARNING: 'auth' is used inconsistently, local='auth SHA256', remote='auth [null-digest]'
Mär 08 09:28:04 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: WARNING: 'keysize' is used inconsistently, local='keysize 256', remote='keysize 128'
Mär 08 09:28:04 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: [tallinn-rack404.nodes.gen4.ninja] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]95.153.32.89:443
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: /usr/lib/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --debug 0 27397 --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_4 --tun -- tun0 1500 1552 10.203.6.105 255.255.255.0 init
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2899] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2962] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2968] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",6:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2977] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",6:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP6 Config Get) reply received
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <warn>  [1615195685.2978] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",6:(tun0)]: invalid IP6 config received!
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <warn>  [1615195685.2979] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",6:(tun0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: GID set to nm-openvpn
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: UID set to nm-openvpn
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: net_addr_v4_del: 10.203.6.105 dev tun0
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-1): Operation not permitted
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2995] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: Linux can't del IP from iface tun0
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2995] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc NetworkManager[615]: <info>  [1615195685.2995] vpn-connection[0x56199a770540,5ac753b0-ffeb-4bd7-bfd2-a4782fc25797,"CG_Estland",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Mär 08 09:28:05 pwrpc nm-openvpn[27404]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
```

I already have ipv6 deactivated in the connection editor.

here is the conent of an ovpn file:

```
client
remote 87-1-cz.cg-dialup.net 443
dev tun 
proto udp
auth-user-pass


resolv-retry infinite 
redirect-gateway def1
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
cipher AES-256-CBC
ncp-disable
auth SHA256
ping 5
ping-exit 60
ping-timer-rem
explicit-exit-notify 2
script-security 2
remote-cert-tls server
route-delay 5
verb 4


ca ca.crt

cert client.crt

key client.key
```

Any idea why this might be? Is there a better way to connect to vpn providers in linux?

Best regards

Comment: Have you contacted CyberGhost support to see if they can help you?

Comment: Haven't thought about that. I will do that. Maybe I can also ask them if they can adjust their script for my distro.

Comment: I asked cyberghost and they told me they might be developing an arch port.

Anyways. I just managed to connect by downgrading OpenVPN.
Code:
sudo pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/o/openvpn/openvpn-2.4.9-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260567

Comment: Cool! Please post that as a slightly fuller answer and self-accept that. Useful info that I think others can use.

Comment: when I fixed the leak I will update the post. thanks

Comment: Good work! This is a helpful thread right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked CyberGhost and they told me they **might** be developing an Arch Linux port. Nothing specific.

For now I managed to connect by downgrading OpenVPN as [explained here](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260567):

```
sudo pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/o/openvpn/openvpn-2.4.9-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

If using GTK network editor, diable IPv6 in LAN/WiFi connection settings to prevent leakage of IP info. Do this only for CyberGhost which doesn't support IPv6.

Unfortunately I’m getting IPv4 leaks. I can’t remember how I fixed it in the past but might try what is explained in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/PRry7Qhh8AM).

Will update this answer when I find a fix.

---

**Found a fix to the leaks:**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434916/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak

Look for your installed NetworkManager VPN connections (the '$' is just my system prompt, to show you're at the command line in a terminal window):

```
$ ls -la /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

Then choose the one you want to fix and run this command on it (or you can just edit the config file manually, as this command just adds a dns-priority entry under section ipv4):

```
$ sudo nmcli connection modify <vpn-connection-name> ipv4.dns-priority -42
```

And restart:

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

**No clue what that does. So if anybody has an idea I would be interested to hear.**

Comment: weird. it only leaks when I have my torrent client opened. adding the lines mentioned in the video to the .ovpn file does nothing.

Comment: and it also reveals my real ip in the torrent client. https://imgur.com/FCv1Re3

Comment: https://imgur.com/ePu6ARK.png